# The limit of $(s_j)$ when said $(s_j)$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose that we have a sequence $(s_j)$ that is finite (where $j$ is an element of the natural numbers); it has $j$ terms. Can we say that $(s_j)$ has a limit? Also what about convergence? Can we say that $(s_j)$ converges to some number? I would think no on both cases. What about subsequences? Can we say that they have limits or that they converge if they are finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, but doing so is not really useful. A finite set of integers trivially forms a "directed set", meaning that it can be used as the domain of a "net", a sort of generalized sequence. The reason this is not useful is that every such net converges, and converges to its last value. Depending on what space you're working on, it may or may not converge to other values, but it does not, under any circumstances I can think of, have any useful or interesting properties.

Comment: What reference can I look this on?

Comment: @user97554, if you want to learn about nets, an early but good text is Kelley's *General Topology*, which uses them extensively (be warned that his definition of "order" is utterly non-standard). Munkres' *Topology* uses them to a certain extent as well. If you just want to get the definitions check out Wikipedia or ProofWiki.